# MongoDB retrieving one of each element with one query

Tags: mongodb, pymongo, nosql

Take a collection with a number of elements that belonging to specific groups - for the sake of example let's say it looks something like this:

```
collection = db['news'] 
{'source': 'New York Times', 'article_name': xxx, 'data_published': xxx, 'link': xxx,'index': xxx, 'first_paragraph': xxx } 
{'source': 'Hacker News', 'article_name': xxx, 'data_published': xxx, 'link': xxx,'index': xxx, 'first_paragraph': xxx }
```

Suppose I want to retrieve the most recent articles for each *different* {'source'} in the collection, such that the return of the query will be the latest published article (one) 'New York Times, the latest published article (one) for 'Hacker News' etc.

Can this be done in a single query, or will it have to be multiple queries, if the later is the case won't I first have to build a list of unique 'sources' and than query for one article from each?

Follow-Up: How would it be possible to get sub-groupings, i.e. suppose the database entries also have an author:

```
{'source': 'New York Times', 'author': xxx, 'article_name': xxx, 'data_published': xxx, 'link': xxx,'index': xxx, 'first_paragraph': xxx } 
    {'source': 'Hacker News', author': xxx, 'article_name': xxx, 'data_published': xxx, 'link': xxx,'index': xxx, 'first_paragraph': xxx }
```

And the goal is to return one entry per "author" (as previously, but also grouped as an array or dictionary by "source")

Comment: you can do it with [aggregation framework](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/aggregation/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use aggregation framework to get what you want:

```
db.news.aggregate([
    { $sort: { "data_published": -1 } },
    {
        $group: {
            _id: "$source",
            name: {
                $first: "$article_name"
            },
            link: {
                $first: "$link"
            }
        }
    }
]);
```

**Edit** 
If you want to group by multiple fields you need to change the `_id` parameter in the `$group` to:

```
_id : { source : "$source", author : "$author" }
```

This will first sort your documents by the `data_published` field and then group by `source`. The `$first` operator will only take the value that it encounters.

For further detail you can check the documentation for [$group](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/#pipe._S_group) operator.

Comment: How efficient is this compared to the alternatives? i.e. having an array of articles within a source, i.e. "source": "hacker news", "articles": [x1, x2, x3] or separate collections?

Comment: @user3467349 I think that this structure is the most efficient you can get. You have a limit of 16MB per doc, so storing all articles in one doc is probably out of the question. Separating them into N separate collections will mean that you will have to do N queries to get your results

Comment: How could I get sub-groupings in the result? I edited my question -